# Trefethen & Bau Question 39.3. on Bi-Conjugate Gradients

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

So, I've been stuck on this problem (Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen & Bau, Problem 39.3.) for a while now.
[image]
The idea is to choose suitable starting vectors in the BCG algorithm to reduce it to certain "special" cases, where the BCG algorithm (Algorithm 39.1.) is something like
[image]

The first part is trivial, since Algorithm 38.1. is the *Conjugate Gradients* method, reproduced below
[image]

For this, it is sufficient to take $\boldsymbol{s}_0 = \boldsymbol{r}_0$, and everything reduces nicely to just the inner loop of CG being run twice per iteration. I'm not sure what exactly is needed for (b), though. I considered the choice $\boldsymbol{s}_0 = A\boldsymbol{r}_0$ but I'm not sure what direction I am supposed to go with this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it appears for (a) part, you need $s_{n-1}^{\ast} = r_{n-1}^T$, then that is $s_{n-1} = \overline{r_{n-1}}$ and $q_{n-1} = \overline{p_{n-1}}$. So that is to say $s_0 = \overline{r_0}$?